# How to update color of streamplot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

If have a streamplot:

```
c = streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=(0,0,0,1))
```

Now, I want to hide it:

```
c.lines.set_alpha(0)
c.arrows.set_alpha(0)
draw()
```

The lines disapear, but not the arrows. Why? How can I change the alpha of the arrows? ('Im using qt4agg backend).

Answer (score 5):

That's... bizarre. As far as I can tell, *anything* done to c.arrows doesn't actually change any of the arrows: `c.arrows.set_visible(False)` also does nothing. This is the case for both the Qt4Agg and iPython Inline backends.

One solution is to set the alpha/visibility directly on each arrow. For example, you could do the following:

```
for x in gca().get_children():
    if type(x)==matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch:
        x.set_alpha(0) # or x.set_visible(False)
draw()
```

You may want to replace gca() with a specific axis.

This is not at all ideal, and I'm assuming there's some sort of bug involved. I'll have to look into it more closely.

---

Edit:

So, there are a few things here. Essentially, the `c.arrows` PatchCollection is completely useless, as best I can tell:

- `streamplot`, in streamplot.py, *doesn't add the `c.arrows` PatchCollection to the axis at all*. Instead, it adds the FancyArrowPatches directly.
- Even if it did, [PatchCollection does not work with FancyArrowPatch](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Problem-with-PatchCollection-and-FancyArrowPatch-td40372.html).
- There was supposed to be an issue filed about this, but it apparently was never done. I might work on it if I have a chance.

At the very least, the documentation should make clear that `c.arrows` is not a real collection and instead appears to be a bogus, useless object mean for future-compatibility.